# Complex analysis removable singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Not sure if this is the place to ask but I just read in my textbook

> If $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$, $f$ is bounded in some punctured neighbourhood of $z_0$.

So my question is why is $f$ bounded in this case?

Comment: If $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ then there is an analytic function $g$ defined in a neighborhood of $z_0$ such that $f(z)=g(z)$ on the punctured neighborhood. Since $g$ is continuous, it is bounded on the neighborhood, hence so is $f$.

Comment: Is this a theorem? Sorry I don't quite understand why this is the case

Comment: It is a definition. What do you mean by a removable singularity?

Comment: This is proved by Riemann’s Removable Singularity Theorem. The best discussion that I have found on this topic is at https://youtu.be/Xby4KYQCExA and second best IMO is here: https://youtu.be/FEAPeT0-3EY

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ then the principal part of its Laurent series equals $0,$ therefore Laurent series has only nonnegative powers  $$f(z)=a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+\ldots+a_n(z-z_0)^n+\ldots $$
Then
$\lim\limits_{z\to{z_0}}{f(z)}=a_0.$

Comment: Well it's just a power series with positive powers still not sure why it is bounded

Comment: It mostly looks like a comment not answer...

Comment: My question is why f is bounded in some punctured neighbourhood around z, not the Laurent series representation of a removable singularity

Comment: What definition of removable singular point are you using? One of definitions is [here](http://planetmath.org/removablesingularity):    Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be an open neighbourhood of a
point $a\in \mathbb{C}$.  We say that a function
$f:U\backslash\{a\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has a **removable singularity** at
$a$, if the complex derivative $f'(z)$ exists for all $z\neq a$, and
if $f(z)$ is  bounded near $a.$